# Remove selected text using regular expressions

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7

I have a large html block and I want to remove all `<img>` elements, but NOT their text parts.  So maybe there is something like this:

```
<a href="http:">Some text</a> Some other text <img height="1" picture.gif> MORE TEXT </img>
```

If I use BeautifulSoup to extract all the img tags, I also lose the associated text ("MORE TEXT" in the above example).  So instead I decided to use regular expressions on the entire html before making the soup.  I want to remove every `"<img"` through the next `">"`, and then also every `"</img>"`.  This should leave the text behind.

So here's my attempt:

```
while myhtml.find('<img/') > 0:
    re.sub( r'<img .*?>', '', myhtml , flags=re.DOTALL)
    re.sub( r'</img>', '', myhtml , flags=re.DOTALL)
```

I ran this and all the img parts are still there.  Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a large html block and I want to remove all `<img>` elements, but NOT their text parts.

You can avoid using regular expression here..

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                            
>>> html = '<a href="http:">Some text</a> Some other text <img height="1" picture.gif> MORE TEXT </img>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for m in soup.findAll('img'):
>>>     m.replaceWithChildren()

>>> print soup

<a href="http:">Some text</a> Some other text  MORE TEXT
```

If you still prefer to use a regular expression and just wanted to remove all `<img ..>` and `</img>` tags:

```
re.sub(r'</?img[^>]*>', '', html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex to match the `<img>` elements:

```
(?<!(<[^>]*))(</?img[^>]*>)
```

The first part of the regex, `(?<!(<[^>]*))`, asserts a negative look-behind that the `<img>` element is not within another open tag element. This should account for cases such as those where the tag occurs within a string.

The second part of the regex, `(</?img[^>]*>)`, matches the `<img...>` and `</img>` tag elements.